# Why is my background styling getting ignored?

Tags: css, reactjs, styling

I have this a scrollable component:

```
<div>
  <div className="scrolling-component">...</div>
  <div className="button">...</div>
</div>
```

And in the scss file I have:

```
.scrolling-component {
  background: linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 70%) 0 100%, radial-gradient(50% 0, farthest-side, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(50% 100%, farthest-side, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

But I checked the dev tools and it looks like there's something wrong with the syntax, I've been looking at it for a while now and have yet to figure out what exactly is wrong with it, I was thinking perhaps it's the radial-gradient, help is appreciated!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: What do your dev tools show you? Also, doesn't react use className instead of class?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry typo! It is className, and it shows the style crossed out with a yellow warning triangle to the left of it

Comment: That means there is an error in that line of code. That is what the browser Developer Tools is telling you

Comment: Yes, I've narrowed it down to the syntax for the `radial-gradient`, specifically the positioning. But I can't figure out why it's complaining about using percentages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and dev tools are showing error 'Invalid property value' in background. you forgot to add 'at' in radial gradient:
working gradient:

```
linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 70%) 0 100%, radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
```